# Loading Flexslider dynamically via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, load, flexslider

I have a page index.html with a menu that dynamically loads content from pages 1.html, 2.html, 3.html, etc via AJAX into a DIV in index.html.

The content in 1.html has a Flexslider built in, which does not get initalized after it is loaded via AJAX. If I make a direct call / refresh the page, the slider loads perfectly!

I call the slider in index.html via

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
    manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li"
    });
 });
</script>
```

My AJAX call is in a external .js and looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav2mobile li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content2';
        $('#content2').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#nav2mobile li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content2';
    $('#content2').hide('normal',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#load').fadeIn('slow');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content2').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content2').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

});

I can't figure out how to start the slider after it has been loaded into index.html

I tried putting the Slider call into the `.click(funktion()` but that didn't work either..

Anyone an idea?

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try changing the `$(window).load(function()` for `$(document).ready(function ()` ?

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)